# Question about return in lamba expression

Tags: lambda, kotlin

First here is my code

```
fun <T> max(strings : List<T>, compare : (acc:T, nextElement : T) -> Boolean) : T {

     var s : T = strings[0]
     for (t in strings) {
     if(compare(s,t)) 
         s = t
     }

     return s
}

fun lookForAlice (people : ArrayList<out Person>) {  

     people.forEach{ if (it.name == "Alice") {println("Found"); return}}
}

fun main() {

    val ints : List<Int> = listOf(1,333,44,3333)
    println(max(ints, {a, b -> if(a < b) {return true}}))  // Error Here!!!     
}
```

I know there can be 'return' in lambda expression, But I have error on the line I remarked.. What is wrong about it???

Answer (score 3):

Lambda expressions normally don't have an explicit `return` statement. Instead, the return value is simply the result of the last (or only) expression, so you just need this:

```
{ a, b -> a < b }
```

If you really want an explicit `return`, you must qualify it with a *label*. Kotlin autogenerates one for you; its name is the function to which you pass the lambda:

```
{ a, b -> if (a < b) return@max true else return@max false }
```

Note that you must have an `else` part; otherwise, Kotlin doesn't know what to return if the comparison is false.

Or, because `if` is an expression:

```
{ a, b -> return@max if (a < b) true else false }
```

...but `if (x) true else false` constructs are discouraged, because it's equivalent to just `x`.

An unlabeled return always returns from the enclosing "proper" function, not from the lambda.

Comment: Well.. sorry for my explanation. But why                                                
people.forEach{ if (it.name == "Alice") {println("Found"); return}} is allowed and        
 {a, b -> if(a < b) {return true}} is not allowed in my case??

Comment: Only the language designers can tell you why they did it this way. My guess is that because the primary purpose of lambda expressions is to write fairly small functions, it is convenient to be able to omit `return`. And sometimes, you do want to inside a lambda function to decide to return from its parent function. I don't know why they chose to make the latter the default.

Comment: `{ if (it.name == "Alice") {println("Found"); return}` is a lambda that causes all of `lookForAlice()` to return once you've found Alice. But in your `max()` call, the lambda is for comparing the elements, and you don't want to return from `main()` once you've compared the first pair of elements.

Comment: The reason you're getting a syntax error on `{ a, b -> if (a < b) { return true } }` is that this lambda only contains one top-level expression, which is the `if`. But if you use `if` as an expression, you must also have an `else` part. Try `{ a, b -> if (a < b) { return true } else { return false } }` and see that it doesn't do what you want: nothing will be printed because the first time the lambda is invoked by `max()`, the lambda tells `main()` to return.